# Is it possible to get the transaction hash from within a Solidity function call?

Tags: solidity, transactions

Within a Solidity function, is the transaction hash available as a global variable from within the contract? I would have thought it would be something like `tx.hash`
in the same way you can do `tx.origin` etc.

My thinking is that the transaction hash will not be available until the contract has been mined. Is this correct?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/can-a-contract-view-the-details-of-a-transaction-given-a-transaction-id

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Here](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#global-variables) you have all the global variables in Solidity:

> **Global Variables**
>
> - block.coinbase (address): current block miner’s address
> - block.difficulty (uint): current block difficulty
> - block.gaslimit (uint): current block gaslimit
> - block.number (uint): current block number
> - block.blockhash (function(uint) returns (bytes32)): hash of the given block - only works for 256 most recent blocks
> - block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp
> - msg.data (bytes): complete calldata
> - msg.gas (uint): remaining gas
> - msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)
> - msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message
> - now (uint): current block timestamp (alias for block.timestamp)
> - tx.gasprice (uint): gas price of the transaction
> - tx.origin (address): sender of the transaction (full call chain)
> - keccak256(...) returns (bytes32): compute the KECCAK256 hash of the (tightly packed) arguments
> - sha256(...) returns (bytes32): compute the SHA256 hash of the (tightly packed) arguments
> - ripemd160(...) returns (bytes20): compute RIPEMD of 256 the (tightly packed) arguments
> - ecrecover(bytes32, uint8, bytes32, bytes32) returns (address): recover public key from elliptic curve signature
> - addmod(uint x, uint y, uint k) returns (uint): compute (x + y) % k where the addition is performed with arbitrary precision and does not
>   wrap around at 2**256.
> - mulmod(uint x, uint y, uint k) returns (uint): compute (x * y) % k where the multiplication is performed with arbitrary precision and
>   does not wrap around at 2**256.
> - this (current contract’s type): the current contract, explicitly convertible to address
> - super: the contract one level higher in the inheritance hierarchy
> - selfdestruct(address): destroy the current contract, sending its funds to the given address
> - <address>.balance: balance of the address in Wei
> - <address>.send(uint256) returns (bool): send given amount of Wei to address, returns false on failure.

As you say, as the transaction is not mined you can't find here the `tx.hash`.

Comment: It's the same reason you can't do `block.hash(block.number)`, since the blockhash depends on the result of the contract execution, so it's a circular reference.

Comment: Actually, the transaction hash only depends on the data of the transaction (example: 0xabc sends 0xcde 10 Ether with nonce n, gas g...), not its execution.

Comment: The TxHash is known indeed before the block is mined. It is the first info the caller get in the callback. So why cannot it be available in the EVM. This would be nice.

Comment: @GuenoledeCadoudal Sounds like a good question to ask.

Comment: @GuenoledeCadoudal because when EVM is running the transaction, its data is not completely made, and so its hah cannot be determined.

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji this might be a misunderstanding. The tx hash is the value calculated with only the input of the transaction and is calculated before it reaches the EVM since it is returned to the caller (the program outside making the transaction) so it can check the transaction state. The question is "would it be possible / interesting to bring that tx hash as a constant in the solidity language?" like you have the current tx.origin. A tx.hash for instance.

Comment: I have a use case where this would fit well! I have a dapp that's trying to keep track of when major events happen, and I would love for my contract go be able to store and recall the TX if it was important!

Comment: The transaction hash does not depend on the mining process. The transaction (along with its hash) exists in the mempool before the block is mined.