# Can a contract view the details of a transaction, given a transaction id?

Tags: transactions, contract-development, blockchain

Can a contract view the details of a transaction, given a transaction id?

More generally, what details of the blockchain is a given contract aware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a contract only has access to the *current* state of the blockchain, and transactions are not part of state.

Specifically, these functions are available in Solidity for examining the current state:

> block.coinbase (address): current block miner’s address
>
> block.difficulty (uint): current block difficulty
>
> block.gaslimit (uint): current block gaslimit
>
> block.number (uint): current block number
>
> block.blockhash (function(uint) returns (bytes32)): hash of the given
>
> block - only works for 256 most recent blocks
>
> block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp
>
> msg.data (bytes): complete calldata
>
> msg.gas (uint): remaining gas
>
> msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)
>
> msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message
>
> now (uint): current block timestamp (alias for block.timestamp)
>
> tx.gasprice (uint): gas price of the transaction
>
> tx.origin (address): sender of the transaction (full call chain)
>
> <address>.balance: balance of the address in Wei
>
> <address>.send(uint256) returns (bool): send given amount of Wei to address, returns false on failure.

[Docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#global-variables)