# Can a smart contract know its address where it has been mined?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-design

I'm using Solidity in order to create smart contracts. From [contract only has access to the current state](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/can-a-contract-view-the-details-of-a-transaction-given-a-transaction-id), I can't see where I'm able to get directly the address where this contract has been mined.

The only way I see to achieve this, is to use the `Web3 JavaScript` API so as to get `contract.address`, and then call a setter function,implemented inside the smart contract with `contract.address` as input parameter.

Is this the only way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can get the contract address before it has been mined: https://github.com/b9lab/cyclical-reference/blob/master/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js#L6-L7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the global variable `this`.

```
address myAddress = address (this)
```