# how to get TXrecipt of transaction from within Solidity smartcontract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-design

I want to keep one condition where transaction status is derived from TXhash so 
is there any way in where i can retrieve inside solidity smart-contract so that can get transaction status from it and check the condition. 
so do solidity have any function like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A function should not depend on transactions in the past. That's the state's job. You should never need to look back.

And, it won't work. [Can a contract view the details of a transaction, given a transaction id?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/can-a-contract-view-the-details-of-a-transaction-given-a-transaction-id)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, because smart contracts live on the blockchain, which essentially is a list of transactions, or 'history'. Transactions that are not mined yet, are not part of the blockchain 'history'. That means that **for a smart contract, transactions don't exist until they are executed, or mined**.

To check that a transaction was mined, you will have to check the effects it has had to the state of the blockchain. You could store the hash of a transaction you need to check in a `mapping(bytes32 => bool)` whenever a certain function is called. That depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: How would you get the hash of the transaction as mentioned in your answer?