# Why is the transaction hash (tx.hash) not available in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Why not solidity provide tx.TxHash (only tx.gasprice , tx.origin)?

reference https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html，

tx.TxHash，Transaction(ID) Hash, it should be a random num。

thanks.

Comment: Possible related the comments of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/is-it-possible-to-get-the-transaction-hash-from-within-a-solidity-function-call/2665#2665. It should be possible, but it is not implemented.

Comment: Out of interest what do you want this for?