# Why transaction hash isn't available inside solidity function call

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, ethereumj

I recently bumped into this
[Is it possible to get the transaction hash from within a Solidity function call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/is-it-possible-to-get-the-transaction-hash-from-within-a-solidity-function-call) while I was looking for a way to save the transaction hash inside my contract. And accoriding to that thread the transaction hash is not available as global variable inside solidity contracts. So I am wondering, why it is not available although the hash is predetermined?, Is there a reason for that?